# Nested array into menu, but with urls generation

Tags: php, url, multidimensional-array, menu, nested

Pleaser help to create menu with nested urls.

**I have a mulidimentual array, like this:**

```
["Увлажнение"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Туалетная вода"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Духи и парфюмерная вода"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Мужские аксессуары"]=>
  array(13) {
    ["Часы"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["Часы"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    ["Сумки и чехлы"]=>
    array(8) {
      ["Спортивные сумки"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["Сумки"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["Рюкзаки"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
```

**I have a function that create HTML Menu from this array:**

```
function makeList($array) {

      //Base case: an empty array produces no list
      if (empty($array)) return '';

      //Recursive Step: make a list with child lists
      $output = '<ul>';

      foreach ($array as $key => $subArray) {

            $url = URLify::filter ($key);

             $output .= '<li><a href="'.$url.'">' . $key .'</a>'. makeList($subArray) . '</li>';

      }

      $output .= '</ul>';

      return $output;

  };
```

**That generame manu like:**

- Увлажнение
- Туалетная вода
- Духи и парфюмерная вода
- Мужские аксессуары

  - Часы
- Сумки и чехлы

  - Спортивные сумки
  - Сумки

**Every menu urls like:**

- uvlazhnenie
- tualetnaya-voda
- duhi-i-parfyumernaya-voda
- muzhskie-aksessuary
- chasy

But i need urls like:
**muzhskie-aksessuary/chasy**

With nested (with delemiter) urls.

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a second argument for your function for this:

```
function makeList($array, $url = '') {
    //Base case: an empty array produces no list
    if (empty($array)) return '';
    //Recursive Step: make a list with child lists
    $output = '<ul>';
    foreach ($array as $key => $subArray) {
        $url2 = $url . ($url == '' ? '' : '/') . URLify::filter ($key);
        $output .= '<li><a href="'.$url2.'">' . $key .'</a>'. makeList($subArray, $url2) . '</li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Nope, because, all previous elements will be added to url (( uvlazhnenie/tualetnaya-voda/duhi-i-parfyumernaya-voda/muzhskie-aksessuary/chasy/chasy

Comment: But i need only parents((

Comment: Thanks, but now, all urls first level(((, The same as mine((

Comment: Did you pass the second argument?

Comment: echo "<ul>";
echo makeList($nested_array,"");
echo "</ul>";

Comment: One more fix: need `$url . ` after assignment to `$url2`. See update, and running on [eval.in](https://eval.in/663992)

Comment: Done. Thanks for help.